# How to load a Linux .so file by Google Test?

Tags: linux, googletest

I'm new at ***gTest***, and I need to write a program through **Linux** platform.
But when I start to write it, I don't know how to load `.so` file.
In **Windows**, I load files like how I load `.dll` file by

```
HINSTANCE dllInstance = ::LoadLibraryW(L"example.so");
```

Which loads successfully.
Does anyone here know how to load .so file?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia (of all places) has some [code examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading#Most_UNIX-like_operating_systems_.28Linux.2C_.2ABSD.2C_Solaris.2C_etc..29) that provide a good starting point.

For more details see [`dlopen()`'s man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), then those of `dlsym()`, `dlclose()`, `dlerror()`.

Comment: Thanks, It works! But now I have another problem. By this way, how to load these functions inside the .so file?

Comment: @user3462776 Just read on in that article, specifically the sections [Extracting Library Contents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading#Extracting_Library_Contents) and [Converting Extracted Library Contents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading#Converting_Extracted_Library_Contents). And don't forget to close.